How to handle multi states
i am building an app with flutter and firebase backed in which the user can go to a profile screen to edit it.
The profile has 2 parts, a view one, where the user can view all its data, verify its email and change its profile picture and an edit one when he can change email, name and bio.
Both of this pages consist of a bloc builder that listens to AuthBloc. Authbloc has multiple stages, AuthLoading, Success, the state for the user class and authstatus, etc. The problem is that I need something that always has the latest user information, because if the user clicks on verify or changes its profile picture in the first edit page, the user state will be lost when navigating to the second page.
View Page Code:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/core/common/roles/roles.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/core/common/widgets/not_signed_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/core/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/features/profile/pages/profile_screen_edit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/features/profile/widgets/delete_account.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/features/profile/widgets/email_verified.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/features/profile/widgets/profile_header.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/features/profile/widgets/verify_email.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/features/auth/presentation/auth_bloc/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = Constants.profile;
  const ProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  bool _showCheckEmailMessage = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 600,
                child: AppBar(
                  actions: [
                    BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                        buildWhen: (previous, current) {
                      if (current is AuthAppState) {
                        return current.status == AppStatus.authenticated;
                      }
                      return false;
                    }, builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is AuthAppState &&
                          state.status == AppStatus.authenticated) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ProfileEditScreen(
                                            maxwidth: 500,
                                            edit: (field, value) {
                                              context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                                                  AuthChangeField(
                                                      field, value));
                                            },
                                          )));
                                }),
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    })
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(Constants.padding),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600),
                child: BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                  listener: (context, state) {
                    if (state is AuthVerifyEmailMessage) {
                      setState(() {
                        _showCheckEmailMessage = true;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  buildWhen: (previous, current) {
                    if (current is AuthAppState) {
                      return current.status == AppStatus.authenticated;
                    }
                    return false;
                  },
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is AuthAppState &&
                        state.status == AppStatus.authenticated) {
                      final user = state.user;
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          // Profile Card
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                  .colorScheme
                                  .primaryContainer,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                  children: [
                                    ProfileHeader(
                                      profileImageUrl:
                                          user.public.profileImageUrl,
                                      editable: true,
                                      radius: 60,
                                      onDone: (image) {
                                        context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                                            AuthChangeField("profileImageUrl",
                                                base64.encode(image)));
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          user.public.name,
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .bodyLarge,
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 4),
                                        Text(
                                          user.public.bio,
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .bodyMedium,
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 4),
                                        Text(
                                          DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd(
                                                  AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                                      ?.localeName)
                                              .format(user.readOnly.createdAt),
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .bodySmall,
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 4),
                                        if (!(user.readOnly.roles.length == 1 &&
                                            user.readOnly.roles.first ==
                                                Role.user))
                                          Text(
                                            user.readOnly.roles
                                                .map((role) =>
                                                    getLocalizedRoleName(
                                                        role, context))
                                                .join(', '),
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .bodySmall,
                                          ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                  .colorScheme
                                  .primaryContainer,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  user.private.email,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                                _showCheckEmailMessage
                                    ? Text(
                                        "Check email inbox",
                                        style: Theme.of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .bodyMedium
                                            ?.copyWith(color: Colors.green),
                                      )
                                    : user.private.emailVerified
                                        ? const EmailVerified()
                                        : VerifyEmail(
                                            onPressed: () => context
                                                .read<AuthBloc>()
                                                .add(const AuthVerifyEmail()),
                                          ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          if (user.private.phone != "")
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                user.private.phone!,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                              ),
                            ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                  .colorScheme
                                  .primaryContainer,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                                  onPressed: () => context
                                      .read<AuthBloc>()
                                      .add(const AuthLogout()),
                                  child: Text(
                                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.logout),
                                ),
                                DeleteAccount(
                                  onPressed: () => context
                                      .read<AuthBloc>()
                                      .add(const AuthDelete()),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const NotSignedIn();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}




Edit Page Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/core/common/widgets/common_alert.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/core/entities/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart'; // Add this import for bloc
import 'package:flutter_application_1/features/auth/presentation/auth_bloc/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class ProfileEditScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final double maxwidth;
  final Function edit; // Modify as necessary
  const ProfileEditScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.maxwidth,
    required this.edit,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileEditDialogState createState() => _ProfileEditDialogState();
}

class _ProfileEditDialogState extends State<ProfileEditScreen> {
  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _controllers = {
    "name": TextEditingController(),
    "email": TextEditingController(),
    "bio": TextEditingController(),
    "phone": TextEditingController(),
  };
  String currentField = "name";

  final Map<String, bool> _isEdited = {
    "name": false,
    "email": false,
    "bio": false,
    "phone": false,
  };

  final Map<String, bool> _isSaving = {
    "name": false,
    "email": false,
    "bio": false,
    "phone": false,
  };

  final Map<String, bool> _isSuccess = {
    "name": false,
    "email": false,
    "bio": false,
    "phone": false,
  };
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //listentoAuthSuccess();
    initializeControllers();
  }

  void initializeControllers() {
    final authState = context.read<AuthBloc>().state;
    if (authState is AuthAppState &&
        authState.status == AppStatus.authenticated) {
      _controllers["name"]?.text = authState.user.public.name;
      _controllers["email"]?.text = authState.user.private.email;
      _controllers["bio"]?.text = authState.user.public.bio;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllers.forEach((_, controller) => controller.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Initialize controllers with user data
  void _initializeControllers(UserEntity user) {
    _controllers["name"]?.text = user.public.name;
    _controllers["email"]?.text = user.private.email;
    _controllers["bio"]?.text = user.public.bio;
    _controllers["phone"]?.text = user.private.phone ?? "";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) {
        if (current is AuthAppState) {
          return current.status == AppStatus.authenticated;
        }
        return false;
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        print(state);
        if (state is AuthAppState) {
          _initializeControllers(state.user);
        } else if (state is AuthLoading) {
          // Start showing the loading state for the field being updated
          setState(() {
            _isSaving[currentField] = true;
          });
        } else if (state is AuthSuccess) {
          // After success, show the check mark for 2 seconds
          setState(() {
            _isSaving.updateAll((key, value) => false);
            _isSuccess[currentField] = true;
          });

          // Reset success state after 2 seconds
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
            setState(() {
              _isSaving.updateAll((key, value) => false);

              _isSuccess.updateAll((key, value) => false);
            });
          });
        } else if (state is AuthFailure) {
          setState(() {
            _isSuccess.updateAll((key, value) => false);
            _isSaving.updateAll((key, value) => false);
          });
        } else if (state is AuthVerifyEmailMessage) {
          showMessage(
              context,
              AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                  .confirmation_email_sentTo(state.email),
              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.confirm,
              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.ok);
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthAppState) {
          // Initialize controllers with current user state

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: widget.maxwidth),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.edit_profile,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        // Display the current name
                        _buildEditableField(
                          "name",
                          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.name,
                          TextField(
                            controller: _controllers["name"],
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                currentField = "name";
                                _isEdited["name"] = true;
                              });
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.name,
                              hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                              labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                            ),
                          ),
                          () {
                            final updatedValue = _controllers["name"]?.text;
                            if (updatedValue != null &&
                                updatedValue.isNotEmpty) {
                              widget.edit("name", updatedValue);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 8),
                        _buildEditableField(
                          "bio",
                          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.bio,
                          TextField(
                            controller: _controllers["bio"],
                            minLines: 4,
                            maxLines: 7,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                currentField = "bio";
                                _isEdited["bio"] = true;
                              });
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.bio,
                              hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                              labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                            ),
                          ),
                          () {
                            final updatedValue = _controllers["bio"]?.text;
                            if (updatedValue != null &&
                                updatedValue.isNotEmpty) {
                              widget.edit("bio", updatedValue);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 8),
                        _buildEditableField(
                          "email",
                          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.email,
                          TextField(
                            controller: _controllers["email"],
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                currentField = "email";
                                _isEdited["email"] = true;
                              });
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.email,
                              hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                              labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                            ),
                          ),
                          () {
                            final updatedValue = _controllers["email"]?.text;
                            if (updatedValue != null &&
                                updatedValue.isNotEmpty) {
                              widget.edit("email", updatedValue);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 8),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.close),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return SizedBox
              .shrink(); // Return an empty widget when the state is not AuthAppState
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEditableField(
    String key,
    String label,
    Widget inputWidget,
    VoidCallback onSave,
  ) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: inputWidget),
        if (_isSaving[key] == true)
          CircularProgressIndicator()
        else if (_isSuccess[key] == true)
          Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green)
        else if (_isEdited[key] == true) // Show "Save" button only if edited
          IconButton(
            icon:
                Icon(Icons.save, color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
            onPressed: () {
              onSave();
              setState(() {
                _isEdited[key] = false;
              });
            },
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


AuthBloc State:
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

enum AppStatus { authenticated, unauthenticated }

sealed class AuthState extends Equatable {
  const AuthState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AuthAppState extends AuthState {
  final AppStatus status;
  final UserEntity user;

  AuthAppState({UserEntity? user})
      : user = user ?? UserEntity.empty,
        status = (user?.id == "")
            ? AppStatus.unauthenticated
            : AppStatus.authenticated;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, user];
}

final class AuthVerifyEmailMessage extends AuthState {
  final String email;

  const AuthVerifyEmailMessage({required this.email});
}

final class AuthResetPasswordEmail extends AuthState {
  final String email;

  const AuthResetPasswordEmail({required this.email});
}

final class AuthLoading extends AuthState {}

final class AuthFailure extends AuthState {
  final String message;

  const AuthFailure({required this.message});
}

final class AuthSuccess extends AuthState {}


What is the best what to handle pages that need both user information and other states too?

Usually in scenarios like these, there's 2 best ways you can handle this

Either you should upload your user profile information to your database and use a simple future builder to fetch the latest information each time when you view that information. You can then use that fetched information to pass that to your state provider class to initialize those fields with those latest values when you are editing those values.

Now each time sending a request to Firebase just to view a user information is not ideal. Thus you can also implement a simple caching mechanism with shared preferences or SQLite to locally save these values and update the cache immediately when you update your user information. Use the locally saved values to initialize the state of the values you are dealing with when viewing the view profile page. You can set the values in the void initState() of the page you are viewing.


